# How to execute multiple tasks while scheduler is working?

Tags: python, schedule

I am using the schedule module in python to make a scheduler, the scheduler works, but once it runs my other python programs hang/get stuck..

I am using tkinter to make a UI for the scheduler and schedule module to schedule tasks..

here is the code for my program..

```py
def add_account(name):
    with open(f"---{name}.txt",mode="w")as file:
        file.close()
def write_data(account_name,data):
    with open(f"---{account_name}.txt",mode="a") as file:
        file.write(data + "\n")
        file.close()
def set_remainder(name , data , time2):
    def thing(data, name):
        messagebox.showinfo(f"Reminder Alert for user : {name}", f"The remainder for user: {name} is now!! Remainder:{thing}:")
        return schedule.CancelJob()     
    schedule.every(time2).seconds.do(thing, data, time)
    while True: 
        schedule.run_pending()
        time.sleep(1)
def open_account(name):
    with open(f"---{name}.txt",mode="r") as opened_account:
        remainders = opened_account.read()
        opened_account.close()
    win2 = Tk()
    win2.geometry("100x100")
    remainders = Label(win2, text=remainders)
    remainders.pack()
    new_remainder_label = Label(win2, text="remainder:")
    new_remainder_label.pack()
    new_remainder_entry = Entry(win2)
    new_remainder_entry.pack()


    time_label = Label(win2, text="time:")
    time_label.pack()
    time_entry = Entry(win2)
    time_entry.pack()
    submit_button = Button(win2, text="add reminder", command=lambda:[  write_data(name,new_remainder_entry.get()), set_remainder(name, new_remainder_entry.get(), float(time_entry.get()) )  ])
    submit_button.pack()
    win2.mainloop()
def main():
    main_win = Tk()
    main_win.geometry("100x100")
    account_name_entry = Entry(main_win)
    account_regiter_button = Button(main_win, text="add account", command=lambda:add_account(account_name_entry.get()))
    account_open_button = Button(main_win, text="open account", command=lambda:open_account(account_name_entry.get()))
    account_regiter_button.pack()
    account_open_button.pack()
    account_name_entry.pack()
    main_win.mainloop()
```

thanks in advance..

--CodeMaster.

Answer (score 3):

This is how you use the schedule module to run several jobs parallel.

```
import threading
import time
import schedule


def job():
    print("I'm running on thread %s" % threading.current_thread())


def run_threaded(job_func):
    job_thread = threading.Thread(target=job_func)
    job_thread.start()


schedule.every(10).seconds.do(run_threaded, job)
schedule.every(10).seconds.do(run_threaded, job)
schedule.every(10).seconds.do(run_threaded, job)
schedule.every(10).seconds.do(run_threaded, job)
schedule.every(10).seconds.do(run_threaded, job)


while 1:
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(1)
```

[Source](https://schedule.readthedocs.io/en/stable/faq.html#how-to-execute-jobs-in-parallel)

Comment: So I can run TKinter on the main thread, and the schedule on an other?

Comment: You shouldn´t block the main thread, because "run_pending" needs to be called frequently. Tkinter could block the main loop maybe.
Try to run Tkiter in another thread

Comment: how is that? i don't know much about threading with tkinter, or threading at all for that matter

Answer (score 1):

This behaviour is correct with `schedule` library because once you execute `while` loop, it will loop around that task define with `schedule` library for eternity.

The best way to avoid this is by using python `Threading`.
I have worked with Qt and Tkinter GUI toolkit and I always prefer `Threading` to avoid the deadlock.